# Call/Setup webdriver from DriverSetup.java file in the NameLocator file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to setup the driver here correctly. My output returns NULL.
i am trying to setup driver from driverSetup class and get the placeholder value.

```
public class NameLocator 
{
    String fName;  
    static WebDriver driver;  
    
    public WebDriver setupDriver()
    {
        /*Invoke the getWebDriver method from the DriverSetup File*/
        DriverSetup ds = new DriverSetup();
       
        driver =  ds.getWebDriver();
        return driver;
    
    public String getNameLocator()
    {
       /*Identify the Firstname
         Get the placeholder value
         Store the placeholder value in the static variable fName.*/
     
        if (fName!=null)
        
        fName = driver.findElement(By.name("fname")).getAttribute("placeholder");
        return fName;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException
    {
        NameLocator namLocator=new NameLocator();
        
        String name=namLocator.getNameLocator();
        System.out.println("The name is "+name);
    }

}
```

DriverSetup.java class where all the driver details are given i need to use this in namelocator class and find the placeholder value for firstname. Kindly help me get the code working

```
    public class DriverSetup
    { 
        private static WebDriver driver;
        
        @BeforeClass
        public static WebDriver getWebDriver()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");
            FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
            firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
            FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
            //profile.setPreference("marionette.logging", "TRACE");
            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
            firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
            driver=new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
            String baseUrl = "http://webapps.tekstac.com/Shopify/";
            driver.get(baseUrl);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program starts from main function and it calls the method **getNameLocator** which uses the webdriver object. Your **setupDriver** method which gets the webdriver object from **getWebDriver** has never got executed as you have not called it anywhere.

**Instead of this -- >**

```
 public WebDriver setupDriver()
{
    /*Invoke the getWebDriver method from the DriverSetup File*/
    DriverSetup ds = new DriverSetup();
   
    driver =  ds.getWebDriver();
    return driver;
}
```

**Go with constructor -->**

```
public NameLocator ()
{
    /*Invoke the getWebDriver method from the DriverSetup File*/
    DriverSetup ds = new DriverSetup();
   
    driver =  ds.getWebDriver();
    return driver;
}
```

Explaination on how my constructor code works --> as soon you create object for NameLocator class in **main** method , **Constructor** of NameLocator gets invoked. The constructor will inturn gets the initialized **webdriver** object from **getWebDriver** method

Comment: but my requirement insists that i use the given method to setup the webdriver.

Comment: Even if i add the call the setwebdriver method in the main method. it returns NULL

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException
    {
        NameLocator namLocator=new NameLocator();
        namLocator.setupDriver();
        String name=namLocator.getNameLocator();
        System.out.println("The name is "+name);
    }

}

Comment: What is your initial value of fName ? I don't see it initialized anywhere. You condition says **if (fName!=null)** , go get the fName using-- fName =driver.findElement(By.name("fname")).getAttribute("placeholder");. As you have  not initialized fName, obviously it will have NULL value and the if condition will never gets executed. So you are getting NULL. **Change your if condition to if(fName==NULL)**

Comment: It should work now, if it works, accept my answer by clicking on Tick mark beside your Question under down vote arrow

Comment: Thank you. It worked when i changed the if condition.